# When adding an item to my canvas my object cannot convert

Tags: c#, uwp

I've created an assembly of lines, as an object, which i want to add to my canvas. When i try to call the method I'm being told it cannot convert, at the point of calling it using children.add

My code looks like this:

```
        TimberMember first = new TimberMember(38, 2000, "Horiz");
        first.DrawMember();
        SimpleCanvas.Children.Add(**first**);
```

'TimberMember' is my object, the word 'first' gets the red squigly line and the argument says 'cannot convert from 'Mapping.TimberMember' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement'

Any help would be appreciated, 
thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i managed to figure it out in the end. If I reference the Canvas class alongside timber element then i can add it as a child and then it is being drawn correctly within my canvas.

Answer (score 0):

A Canvas is a XAML control that presents other XAML controls. TimberMember is not a XAML control. XAML controls are objects of type UIElement or they must inherit from type UIElement. TimberMember will need to inherit from UIElement or a type derived from UIElement, like ContentControl, for example.

```
public class TimberMemeber : ContentControl
{
// Your class definition
}
```

This will allow you to add it to the Canvas, but it's not going to help you much because none of its properties will translate into UI content. You haven't told us what TimberMember is or what it's supposed to do, let alone provided the class definition. I can almost 100% guarantee that making it a custom XAML control and adding it to a Canvas is not the correct approach to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do, nor is trying to create a custom XAML control a good idea for someone still learning about OOP fundamentals.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for this, actually i managed to figure it out in the end. If I reference the Canvas class alongside timber element then i can add it as a child and then it is being drawn correctly within my canvas. I will try to follow your method, to form a better understanding, and see if i can make that work too. Many thanks, Matthew